# How do vampires age in the Underworld Universe?

Tags: immortality, underworld

Throughout the franchise we see young children created by vampires:

- Viktor's daughter at young age sees Lucian training and then she is a grown and having a baby
- Amelia's son David

Now history tells that us vampires don't age, so **how is it possible to have them fully mature?**

Like, wouldn't a fetus last a few hundred years in the stomach if ageing is slowed? Is this a movie mistake? Shouldn't they remain children if they are vampires?

Comment: "History tells us that vampires don't age" -- that's a loose, vague statement. Perhaps you could quote some dialogue from one of the movies to support your statement by offering the exact wording of whatever the viewers were told? (I can't help thinking that "a child growing to maturity" might be very different, for a vampire, from "continuing to age as an adult until you're all gray and wrinkled and have arthritic joints and so forth.")

Comment: "History tells us that vampires don't age" — pretty sure it's a subset of fiction that tells us that.

Comment: +1 because I think you have a point here, but your framing needs improvement.  Instead of pointing to other works of fiction to determine that "vampires don't age," you need to point to other *Underworld* characters: Selene, for example, has been 19 years old (canonically) for centuries.